About the use of uint8_t in C when counting
I wanted to make sure that I understood what is happening in the following code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
    uint8_t a = 255;

    a = a + 5;

    printf("%d\n", a);
}

Will the printed value be 4 'cause when a reaches the maximum value it can count to (255) it resets back to 0? And so, if I want to continue counting after a (255), I could create an int variable and add a to it? Like int b = a + 5; that would print 260.

Why would you need a byte accumulator when you know that it will overflow?

@YvesDaoust There's many situations where it is handy in hardware-related programming. Suppose for example that I have a 8 bit CPU, which prefers 8 bit sized variables for performance reasons. Then every second time I call a function, I want something to happen: void func (void) { static uint8_t x; if(x & 1) { do_something(); } x++; } Here the variable will wrap-around eventually but we don't need to know or care about what value it holds.

@Lundin: sure, but here the OP explicitly mentions counting above 255.

@YvesDaoust It's more about understanding what's happening than what'd be smarter to do.

Yes to both questions.
Given that a is a uint8_t, a + 5 is equivalent to (int)a + 5 and produces an int.
When doing arithmetic on pairs of values, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed. If the type of both values are integer types, then this refers to performing the integer promotion of both operands, plus additional steps if the promoted values are still of different types.
Integer promotion refers to converting a value with a type of lesser rank than int into an int (if their whole range can fit in an int) or an unsigned int. uint8_t is guaranteed to be a type of lesser rank than int, and its range is guaranteed to fit in an int, so a value of that type will get promoted into an int.
So, because of the usual arithmetic conversions, a + 5 converts a to an int, adds int 5 to it, producing int 260.
So far, no overflow. But then we assign it to a uint8_t. Converting an overly large a value into an unsigned integer type is well defined. For an 8-bit unsigned integer, you effectively get the result mod 256, which is uint8_t 4.
There would be no overflow if you stored int 260 into an int instead, so that will indeed produce int 260.

Pretty much correct. You just have to realize that in the expression a + 5, the unsigned char is implicitly promoted to the type of 5 which is int, thanks to a promotion rule called "the usual arithmetic conversions". So the addition is actually carried out on int type and you do end up with 260 in a temporary int. And therefore you could indeed do int b = a + 5; and get 260, because the a + 5 part is 260.
During assignment to a in a = a + 5, you force another conversion back to unsigned char, and that one is done "as if by modulus" of one more than the maximum number it can hold. 260 % 256 = 4 so you end up with 4. Which is the very same thing as happens when an unsigned char wraps around.
(Signed integer over-/underflows, which is undefined behavior. Unsigned integers wraps around, which is well-defined behavior.)
If you'd instead write a++; a++; a++; a++; a++; you would get wrap-around.

The usual arithmetic conversions are not a promotion rule. Promotions are a subset of conversions, not the other way around. There are promotion rules inside the usual arithmetic conversions. A promotion never changes the value. Some conversions do, including some of the usual arithmetic conversions.

@lundin Detail: The unsigned char is promoted to int being part of +.  The type of 5 is initially irrelevant for this first step.
